# How can i use id to do action on an object of an android using Robotium tool?

Tags: robotium

I tried to use id to click on the object in an android application but when i enter solo.clickOnImageButton(R.id.action_menu_search); It is showing an error, that action_menu_search cannot be resolved or not a field. How can i use the id of an object to click on the same.

Thank you in advance, 
With regards,
David Gayler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(int id));

Comment: It seems, We have to create another method for that id, am i wright?

Answer (score 0):

Method clickOnImageButton takes parameter as index, not id, so you should use method, which Renas has mentioned.